# Logical equality for two different vector widths

Tags: system-verilog, vivado

Why does logical equality for two vectors of different widths have an output like below?

```
module eq_test;

logic check;
logic [3:0] cmp_0;
logic       cmp_1 = 1'b0;

initial begin
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) begin
        cmp_0 = i;
        check = (cmp_0 == cmp_1);
        $display("%b == %b is %b", cmp_0, cmp_1, check);
    end
end

endmodule
```

With Vivado Simulator

```
0000 == 0 is 1
0001 == 0 is 0
0010 == 0 is 0
0011 == 0 is 0
0100 == 0 is 0
0101 == 0 is 0
0110 == 0 is 0
0111 == 0 is 0
1000 == 0 is 0
1001 == 0 is 0
1010 == 0 is 0
1011 == 0 is 0
1100 == 0 is 0
1101 == 0 is 0
1110 == 0 is 0
1111 == 0 is 0
```

I can assume that the variable with smaller width `cmp_1` is expanded (unsigned expand) to the larger variable width `cmp_0`, is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the variable with smaller width is expanded to the larger variable width.

This is described in IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.6.1 *Rules for expression bit lengths*.

> The number of bits of an expression (known as the size of the
> expression) shall be determined by the operands involved in the
> expression and the context in which the expression is given.

In Table 11-21, the `==` operator has this comment:

> Operands are sized to max(L(i),L(j))

where `i` and `j` represent expressions of an operand, and `L(i)` represents the bit length of the operand represented by `i`.

This is true for all simulators, not just for Vivado.